# print the byte content received from spring controller in angularjs iframe not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, iframe

I need to get an UI-Grid row's content and print while clicking an icon in that row cell.
Everything works perfectly when run the project in *Chrome*.
But *Firefox and IE*, it doesn't print the PDF file.
**This is my app.js code**

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var agentcode = row.entity.agentcode;
var filename = row.entity.fileInfoDO.filename;
iframe.style.display = 'none';
$('#loader').hide();
iframe.src = CONTEXT_PATH+"agent/getFileForPrint?agentcode="+agentcode+"&filename="+filename+"&id="+id;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.focus();
iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

Can anyone help me to solve my problem?